# check internet connection in background service every 30 min

Tags: android, internet-connection, background-service

Hello I want to make an app that will check internet connection in background every 30mins and if so it will send some really small json data to server.

Don't know if doing right but now I have:

```
package com.example.lenovotp.sender;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Calendar;


public class MyClass extends IntentService{
    private static final String TAG = "com.example.lenovotp.sender";
    private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
    private PendingIntent alarmIntent;
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    public MyClass(){
        super("");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    intent = new Intent(this, MyClass.class);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);
    alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            1000 * 30, alarmIntent);

    ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
            activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    //boolean isWiFi = activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI;
    if(isConnected!=false){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Network is avail!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Network is NOT avail!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    }
}
```

And in manifest I have in last postition in  is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- Permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   <service android:name=".MyClass"/>
</application>
```

And in MainActivity

```
package com.example.lenovotp.sender;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MyClass.class);
        startService(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

So now I don't know how to:

1. make it work even app is not running or destroyed by user.
2. it check connectivity every 30mins and if so it sends some data to server.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATED

Comment: so what you want to do? you want to send data or you want to check connection?

Comment: I want to send data.

Comment: and what if time comes and there's no connectivity? what about the data you wanted to send?

Comment: it will be stored in sd card

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things:

1. Subclass `IntentService` instead of `Service`. Services run on the main (UI) thread, but an `IntentService` will do its work in a background thread (in `onHandleIntent()`), and it automatically stops itself after finishing its work.
2. In your service, use `AlarmManager` to schedule your next "wakeup" in 30 minutes. You can find numerous examples how to use `AlarmManager` all over the web.
3. You may need a way to schedule the first "wakeup" of your service after the device boots. For this you'll need a `BroadcastReceiver` in your manifest that is registered to receive the [`ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) broadcast. This requires you to have the `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permission. Examples of this are all over the web as well.

Comment: Hi please could you be more specific on how to implement AlarmManager in onHandleIntent() that I already have? I'm quite lost in all examples in web.

Comment: @N.tsrg 1. You need to use `PendingIntent.getService()`, not `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`, because the intent is intended for your Service class. 2. The alarm interval is in milliseconds. Right now you have `1000 * 30`, which is 30 seconds, not 30 minutes. You need to multiply this by 60 to get 30 minutes. 3. I don't think you need `setRepeating()`, because each time the service runs it should schedule the next wakeup.  I think `setExact()` (or `set()` below API 19) will be enough. Does that make sense?

Comment: Unfortunatly I did changes it makes sense, but it not showing toast. Maybe I'm doing it in wrong class. 30sec is there on purpose to see if it works and changes when I turn off internet. Will help if service is declared below onHandleIntent and just called in it, and the same for alarmManager?

Comment: @N.tsrg I don't see your service declared in your AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Ok I missed that. My bad. Now I don't understand its behavior. I have turned off internet, go run app, it installs and see Toast "Not avail", then I slide down and in the bar turning on internet and swipe up to my app and even after waiting longer time I Toast doesnt change to "Network Avail", and same if i press home button. But if I destroy app it changes Toast to correct one. Then I change conectivity and wait but nothing changes. Could you advice me more on that?

Comment: Ok the last sentence is not true, but it tooks like 5mins to change Toast and second Toast doesnt disappear but stayed behind. Now I can see Toast with longer string behind.